BottomTabNavigator dont shows tabs and coming on top instead of bottom in React Native
My bottom navigator:
firstly, in the top;
secondly, doesnt showing any of my pages;
My code:
App.js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen'
import InternetScreen from './Screens/InternetScreen'
import GroupScreen from './Screens/GroupScreen'

const homeName = "Home"
const internetName = "Internet"
const groupName = "Group"

export default function App() {

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
       <Tab.Navigator>

        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={internetName} component={InternetScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={groupName} component={GroupScreen} />

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

HomeScreen.js and other (they are similar)
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Home Page</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        marginBottom: 16
    }
});

export default HomeScreen;

index.html just creating root for app
i tried all guides that i can find in internet, but nothing can help
result:
enter image description here

Few things to change, move the styles above the function like so. Also if you are on ios please do pod install and then build the app after you have installed the navigation packages.
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
    const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Home Page</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

I tested it out and works fine.


Thanks, but it still doesnt help, I think the problem here is that the tabs is anchored to the top of the page, maybe I need to adjust something further in the css files? im new in web, it can be stupid mistake

I used the exact same styles like you did, and it worked fine.
